# Calling different components into rows in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a very basic question that I cannot comprehend and need some help. I'm creating a really small React project for my personal website. I have `App.js` that is calling all the different components such as `header`, `intro` and etc:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Intro from './Intro';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-6">
                        <Header />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-6">
                        <Intro />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

As you can assume, header is just the top portion of the page and intro (currently) just says some text. This is what it looks like:

[image]

The second component is being blocked by the first component. Can someone explain how React works with components in terms of how it's rendered on the web page? Or is this purely a HTML issue in `App.js`?

Comment: It seems that you used bootstrap to styled your html, check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) on how to used bootstrap navbar.

Comment: It was an issue with my navbar, thank you. Needed to add a body padding for navbars to pad the content.